# When using cucumber and databasecleaner can I keep a single entry in a table?

Tags: database, testing, cucumber, database-cleaner

I am currently using cucumber and databasecleaner to test my application.
And currently in my `env.rb` i have the setup of the cleaner as:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[TABLE]}
After do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

This way I can keep the data in `TABLE`.
But I would also like to keep a single entry in a different table between tests. Is there any way I can achieve that or do I have to recreate it all the time with a `Before` hook?

Comment: So you want to delete all rows but one from your second table?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this hack. Add a `ON DELETE trigger` on that table of your test ENV DB. The trigger invokes a function which inserts the row. You might need to add a check in the function to do nothing if row already exists.

Comment: could you give me an example? I am not sure of how you intend me to do, should I edit my DB??

Comment: Yes you'll have to modify your test DB. For eg. to create trigger in postgres `CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER DELETE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_row();`
And you'll also have to create function add_row() in database which inserts the row if it does not already exists

Comment: I can't edit the DB it is out of my control so is all models views and controls.